# Send message to Chat Bot when while loop is executing

Tags: c#, botframework

I am trying to send a message in the middle of a **while loop** using my bot. Is that possible before breaking? From the code bellow, I am looping and automatically posting message to bot depending on the response state i get from the service.... that is when the value changes. Up to until i get to level 5, I am not breaking. Is there a way i can continue conversation before the loop is actually done?

```
int prev = 2;

do
{
    StatusOption(reply);
    context.Wait(StatusSelected);

    {
        int ride_status = prev;
        context.UserData.TryGetValue<int>("ride_status", out ride_status);
        string trip_status = CheckTripStatus(res[3].ToString());
        prev = ride_status;
        int current = Convert.ToInt32(trip_status);

        if (prev != current)
        {
            if (current == 2)
            {
                reply.Text = "Your driver is coming to pick you.";

                await context.PostAsync(reply);
                context.UserData.SetValue<int>("ride_status", current);
            }
            else if (current == 3)
            {

                reply.Text = "Your driver has arrived.";
                await context.PostAsync(reply);
                context.UserData.SetValue<int>("ride_status", current);
            }
            else if (current == 4)
            {
                reply.Text = "Your trip has started.";
                await context.PostAsync(reply);
                context.UserData.SetValue<int>("ride_status", current);
            }
            else if (current == 5)
            {
                reply.Text = "Your trip has ended.";
                await context.PostAsync(reply);
                context.UserData.SetValue<int>("ride_status", current);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                StatusOption(reply);
                context.Wait(StatusSelected);
            }
        }
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }

}

while (prev <= 5) ;
```

Comment: How about fire up another Thread wich talks without stopping the loop?

Comment: How do i do that @DamoV

Comment: add `using System.Threading;` to your uses and then simply: `new Thread(MyMethod).Start();` where `MyMethod` is a static method you have to create where you can handle all your work in. Or just look at this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_multithreading.htm  But please be patient with starting new Threads in a loop. Otherwise you'll gonna end up with a Bluescreen ;)

Comment: Ok let me try that...will revert

Comment: Where are you doing this loop? Inside your bot code? remember it's an API, not made for synchronous long calls...

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually, it is not a good design practice to consume a context thread in a long running loop.  Check out the **Azure Functions Bot Proactive Template**.  It adds a message that contains a **ConversationReference** to a Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue  A separate function is triggered when anything is added to the queue, and calls the bot to send a message.  This is a more scaleable and manageable design.

When someone requests a ride, you could add their **ConversationReference** to the queue.  Instead of automatically triggering the response, have the function be triggered by changes in the ride status.

---

Another option, not using functions, would be to store the **ConversationReference** somewhere, and expose another WebApi endpoint in your bot's project.  When the status changes, call this endpoint and use the **ConversationReference** to proactively send the rider the status message.  Some proactive messaging documentation can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-proactive-messages?view=azure-bot-service-3.0 (code examples: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/core-proactiveMessages )  Note: these are just examples, and are using static variables.  Nonetheless, they are a good starting point outlining how to do proactive messaging.